# Need to remove WordPress author box from page

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have made new page template on the following page...

https://www.johnnycassell.com/how-to-get-a-girlfriend

I am getting the author box displayed. can anyone help with how to remove this from being displayed? We mainly want to remove it for security.

Comment: Please provide screenshot with marker, so we can get more idea.

Comment: Ok great thanks will try and implement one of these below

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you want to remove lives in the either content.php or single.php or a custom-{slug}.php file you are using for the post. Login as admin to Wordpress, and goto Appearances->Editor. Now edit the file that is in use.

Find the  .author-details css class. Just two divs above it is the ... Remove it and everything inside it to remove the author box.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
<div class="author-details">
<div class="author-image">
<img alt="" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/03e29f93475b2934e049531cadd2d3ba?s=172&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/03e29f93475b2934e049531cadd2d3ba?s=344&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-172 photo" height="172" width="172"></div>
<h5><a href="https://www.johnnycassell.com/author/jhn_cssll_admn" title="Posts by Johnny Cassell" rel="author">Johnny Cassell</a></h5>
<ul class="social-icons">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to add in style.css in your theme

```
     .author-details {
      display: none;
       }
```